# update Migration Command Fails for ConfigurationDbContext and PersistentGrantDbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have  been trying to get IdentityServer4 version 1.5.2 to work for a few days now without success. I am using VS2017
My Entity classes,DataContexts, repositories and migrations are resident in a .Net Standard Library (1.6). So far so good except when I run update-migration command for "PersistenGrantDbContext" and "ConfigurationDbCOntext". I get the error message

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The datacontext classes that i created myself dont seem to have this problem after implementing "IDbContextFactory" interface 
Here I have the implementation for the two culprits

```
public class TemporaryDbContextFactoryScopes : IDbContextFactory<PersistedGrantDbContext>
{
    public PersistedGrantDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PersistedGrantDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=-------;Database=-----------;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
            optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(UserDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
        return new PersistedGrantDbContext(builder.Options, new OperationalStoreOptions());
    }
}

public class TemporaryDbContextFactoryOperational : IDbContextFactory<ConfigurationDbContext>
{
    public ConfigurationDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigurationDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=---------;Database=--------;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
            optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(UserDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));

        return new ConfigurationDbContext(builder.Options, new ConfigurationStoreOptions());
    }
}
```

I have installed the latest version of System.Data.SqlClient still not working

Comment: And the version number of the latest one is 4.1.0.0 like the error reports?

Comment: No the latest version is 4.3.1 but  I managed to solve it just a while ago through unorthodox means

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share what I did to get things rolling. Not sure if that is the right approach though 
First I did this in the class library .csproj

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
```

which turned out to be a bad idea because that was throwing out that error now without it running my migrations with my web app as my start up project return the error "Not context blah blah with name blah blah found"
So I realised  contexts that I created myself worked without glitches so I did this for PersistentGrantDBCOntext and COnfigurationGrantDbContext

```
 public class PGrantDbContext: PersistedGrantDbContext
{
    public PGrantDbContext(DbContextOptions<PersistedGrantDbContext> options, OperationalStoreOptions storeOptions) : base(options, storeOptions)
    {

    }
}
```

and

```
 public ConfigDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions):base(options,storeOptions)
    {

    }
```

and everything went smoothly.
Just not so sure if it is the right approach though

Comment: I' having the following issue:  No parameterless constructor was found on 'PGrantDbContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'PGrantDbContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory<PGrantDbContext>' in the same assembly as 'PGrantDbContext'.    How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I was also in a similar situation few weeks ago and here's how I solved it.

Very similar to yours, I have two projects called `Company.Identity` (`.NETCoreApp`) as my Identity Project and `Company.Identity.Data` (`.NETStandard 1.6`) for migrations. I Use `Company.Identity` Project  as the startup project for migration purposes as it is in the same solution as my data project and I didn't want to clutter the solution with yet another project just as a startup project for migrations.

I followed the tutorial in [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html).

The cli tool reference `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />` is in my `Company.Identity.csproj` file.

**I followed all the steps in the above tutorial except for the following difference**

In `ConfigureServices` method in the `Company.Identity` `Startup` class, I have set the `migrationsAssembly` to `Company.Identity.Data`

```
var migrationsAssembly = "Company.Identity.Data";
```

Note that `Company.Identity` project has already got `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework` nuget package installed. This enabled me to add the migration for `PersistedGrantDbContext`. But when I tried to run migration for `ConfigurationDbContext` it gave me a build error. This was because the migrations generated for `PersistedGrantDbContext` requried `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework` nuget package. So I had to install that in the `Company.Identity.Data project`

I was able to add migrations using the following commands after above changes through command prompt in my `Company.Identity` project.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerPersistedGrantDbMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext -o Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrantDb -p ../Company.Identity.Data

dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerConfigurationDbMigration -c ConfigurationDbContext -o Migrations/IdentityServer/ConfigurationDb -p ../Company.Identity.Data
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

this may help you specially if you have docker-compose in your project. i was able to resolve this issue by removing the docker-compose project and then creating the migrations then adding it again.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60320410/4977086