# Add-Migration while using database in separate Docker container throws an error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've created dockerized ASP.net Core app with auto-generated identity setup (so I've already had by default entity framework configuration). I've created SQL Server as separate container, here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    blazorapp1:
        image: blazorapp1
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on: 
            - db

    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "[SOMEPASSWORD]"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

I've tested database configuration: as Visual Studio generated identity setup for me, I could successfully create new users and they were properly stored in memory.

Then I wanted to create new database table:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<WeightLog> WeightLogs { get; set; }
}
```

To apply those changes, I've used `Add-Migration WeightLogger` in Package Manager Console.

Here is an output:

```
PM> Add-Migration WeightLogger
Build started...
Build succeeded.
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: C:\root\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui\3.1.1\staticwebassets\V4\
Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

There are a couple of things I don't understand here. The first error points me to `C:\root\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui\3.1.1\staticwebassets\V4\` which does not exist. Then there is the second error telling me that `ApplicationDbContext` can't be created. Link points me to webpage that tells:

> When you create a new ASP.NET Core application, this hook is included by default.

So, does this mean I shouldn't need to configure anything? Why it isn't working then? Should I create migrations differently when using Docker container as environment?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue after creating decker-compose for the solution .. did you figure out what is the solution??

Comment: I started to use `docker ef migrations add` command

Comment: I had this same exact issue with a newer version of the microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui package and running the `update-database` command.  I copied the package from `C:\Users\{Username}\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui` to `C:\root\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui` . After doing that I was able to run `update-database` and everything worked as expected.

Comment: @piotrek, if I google "docker ef migrations add" the only result is this page.
Can you please provide a description of how this command works? Running it returns `docker : docker: 'ef' is not a docker command.`

Comment: @JonathanPeel sorry, I probably meant `dotnet ef migrations add` ([link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet)).

Comment: https://dotnetthoughts.net/docker-compose-asp-net-core-application/

Answer (score 5):

I got exactly the same issue and I ended up solving it by deleting the docker-compose project from visual studio and just keep the docker-compose.yaml and manage it through the command line and that solve it.

For those who don't want to remove the docker-compose support for the solution and facing the same issue, I think it is possible to solve it by implementing a design-time interface for the context or using `docker ef migrations add` command but in all cases, it's an issue that should be reported to Microsoft.

Comment: thank you for this one. i have spent almost all day just to resolve this simple issue.

Comment: hi can you explain how / where to run the docker ef migrations add command? the only way i have got this to work is by unloading the docker compose project and making sure my connection strings point to local host. it would be nice to just run a command inside console on the host or in the docker cli for the container. thanks